# Spacing Under Faucet Handle

Tags: bathroom, faucet, sink

I installed some new bathroom faucets, but there is spacing between the counter top and the faucet handle. What can I do or add to fill in the space?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you put a washer or spacer on the top side of the sink that was intended to go on the underside of the sink. Or the washer you did use is upside down. ??

Comment: I can't think of any good reason a faucet would finish like this. I'm going to have to agree with the commenter above; I think you've got something wrong.

Comment: I had someone install them and he said that it was because of the hole...not sure...might get a second opinion..the brand is Pfister before it was Moen but not sure if that matters